# Java 8 Convert a simple List to Map

Tags: java, java-8

```
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        newList.add(1);
        newList.add(2);
        newList.add(3);
        newList.add(4);

        Map<Integer,String> formMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>(); 
        Function<Integer,Map<Integer,String>> myFunc = i->{
          if(i%2==0)
          {
              formMap.put(i,"even");
          }
          return formMap;
        };

        Map<Integer,String> newMap = newList.stream().map(i->myFunc.apply(i)).collect(Collectors.toMap(
        entry -> entry.getKey(), // keyMapper
        entry -> entry.getValue(), // valueMapper
        (first, second) -> first,  // mergeFunction
        () -> new LinkedHashMap<>() // mapFactory
    ));

    }
}
```

How to convert a simple list as above into a map by performing some operations on the objects on list and then putting it in map. 
I took the above Collectors.toMap() code from the net only.
Please help me with the above query/code .

Comment: Sorry i didnt post the error which i was getting. Its coming as below:
**error: cannot find symbol
     Map<Integer,String> newMap = newList.stream().map(i->myFunc.apply(i)).collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable Collectors
  location: class Main
1 error**

Comment: Your imports aren't sufficient, you're missing `java.util.streams.Collectors`.

Comment: The final code looks like 


**Map<Integer,String> newMap =  newList.stream().filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toMap(n -> n, unused -> "even", (a, b) -> a)); **

Comment: You're welcome. Pretty basic error, notice the "error: cannot find symbol [...] symbol: variable Collectors" parts in the error which are a giveaway

Comment: Much better than the original. In particular the original used an impure function in its mapping operation which is a very bad practice.

Comment: No idea, I was already familiar with the functional paradigm so looking up the javadocs was enough for me. I'm sure there are some streams tutorial out there though

Answer (score 3):

Your `map` step converts a `Stream<Integer>` to a `Stream<Map<Integer,String>>`. In order to collect that `Stream` to a single `Map`, you can write:

```
Map<Integer,String> newMap = 
    newList.stream()
           .flatMap(i->myFunc.apply(i).entrySet().stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, // keyMapper
                                     Map.Entry::getValue, // valueMapper
                                     (first, second) -> first,  // mergeFunction
                                     LinkedHashMap::new)); // mapFactory
```

or

```
Map<Integer,String> newMap = 
    newList.stream()
           .map(myFunc)
           .flatMap(m->m.entrySet().stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, // keyMapper
                                     Map.Entry::getValue, // valueMapper
                                     (first, second) -> first,  // mergeFunction
                                     LinkedHashMap::new)); // mapFactory
```

Of course, if all you want is to filter out the odd numbers and map the remaining numbers to "even", you can simply write:

```
Map<Integer,String> newMap = 
    newList.stream()
           .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                     i -> "even",
                                     (first, second) -> first,
                                     LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: A nice one :) Wouldn't look `LinkedHashMap::new` better?